# Destroy timeout for HistoryRecord

Tags: android, android-activity, error-handling, webview

I able to process half the items I have in a ginormous string but I am losing half my data.

Here is my log cat errors.

```
12-08 15:03:44.011: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

12-08 14:40:49.528: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4501c938 package.data/.class1

12-08 14:40:44.318: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450204b8 package.data/.class2
```

Here is what I did, I placed method(which consist of a new bufferReader(new inputstream(String), 8 *1024) in a while loop. The main reason for this is because I am manipulating the string and changing its info on the fly.So in summary I am losing half data but I am able to show half of them. I want to be able to show the remaining.

I understand that this post is similar to other stuff but it seems different. If anyone can assist me in anyway i would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have activities with same code as mentioned all of them?

Comment: Yes, all of my Activities except the .Main one have the same code, but different links in my WebView

Comment: Could you try using private WebView webView; instead of WebView webView;

Comment: How would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if changing the declaration of your activity in the manifest to something like:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity3">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the Manifest, because it start working if I just reduces these Activities or delete some of them that have the same code.

Comment: I would try. No harm in that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add every Activity into your manifest and your Main activity should have the intent filters required to make that your launch one.

Comment: I have added that one, didn't I mention it above?

Comment: You mentioned you added several Activities. I assumed you meant into your project. And you said you added the Internet permission to your manifest, which that alone is not enough. Please post your manifest.

Comment: didn't you see this line that I put above "android:name=".Activity3" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"?

Comment: That's only ONE activity. If you add others to your project, you need to add them in your manifest. Not only just launch one. I think that's your problem.

Comment: I only put one of them for sample, but I have them complete in my Manifest

Comment: And you have the intent filter .MAIN in your launch one? Please post the complete one.

Comment: Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Well, I'd say it look fine. You could clean it by setting the Theme to the application instead of every activity but the rest looks fine. Have you tried cleaning and reinstalling? I've seen problems like this when I changed the launcher activity. Reinstalling and restarting the phone helped.